# Error copying temporary solution file to solutions gallery

Tags: 2013, site, windows-server, template

When I try to save as basic teamsite in SP2013 I get the following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Error copying temporary solution file to solutions gallery: _catalogs/solutions/test4.wsp]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName, String destinationListUrl, Action`1 solutionPostProcessor, Boolean activateSolution) +4119
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SaveAsTemplatePage.BtnSaveAsTemplate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +446
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3586
```

However when I go to _catalogs/solutions/forms/allitems.aspx page I see that the soluton is saved.
When I check the temp folder on the server it contains the wsp file. 
I checked the security on the temp folder and all entries have full control.

What do I miss?

Comment: Go to /_catalogs/solutions/forms/allitems.aspx and upload a wsp file.  Can you do this?

Comment: Tried is and it worked

Comment: After saving the site as a template there a wsp in the solution gallery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was my profile. It was kind of corrupt.

Somehow whenever I logged-in on my SharePoint 2013 server, windows could not find my profile and used a temperary profile.

Removing this profile and restarting the server solved the problem.

[Removing temperary profiles](http://setspn.blogspot.nl/2012/09/temporary-profiles-and-iis-application.html) describes the following various steps to solve the problems

How to fix it if you see those nasty “c:\users\TEMP” folders?

1. Stop the relevant application pools
2. Stop the IIS Admin Service (in services.msc)
3. See that the TEMP folders are gone in c:\users

if the TEMP folders are not disappearing, or you are still getting a temporary profile, you can try to properly cleanup the temporary profile:

1. Stop the application pools
2. Stop the IIS Admin Service
3. Using right-click properties on computer, choose advanced tab and then pick User Profiles. There you can properly delete them.

Comment: can you explain? same thing is happening.

Comment: Whenever I logged on Windows could not find my profile. Then a Temperary profile was loaded. The admins fixed this and removed the profile for me. After restarting the problem was gone. I read somewhere multiple restarts could solve the problem.

Comment: Added some extra information

Answer (score 1):

My fix was because the solution gallery had versioning turned on. I turned it off, logged off, and tried it again.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible in 2013 - try increasing the site template file size as this can be a possible cause for this error: http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=284

Comment: That I tried, but unfortunately it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually activate the feature and check the error.

I had the same issue, the solution was not activating, this solved the issue:
https://erroreimprevisto.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/error-saving-template-sharepoint-2016-attribute-is-not-allowed/