# SP16[OnPrem] - Error copying temporary solution file to solutions gallery (When save site as template)

Tags: error, 2016, site-template, sharepoint-server

I have web site with template "Team site". When i saving site as template;

**Fill template form:**
[image]
**Then i click button OK, and have following error:**
[image]

**This is error by  corelation ID from log files:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error copying temporary solution
>   file to solutions gallery: _catalogs/solutions/LirexTempProject.wsp
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb
>   web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description,
>   ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String
>   workflowTemplateName, String destinationListUrl, Action`1
>   solutionPostProcessor, Boolean activateSolution)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SaveAsTemplatePage.BtnSaveAsTemplate_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

**When i try from PowerShell(have the same error):**
[image]

Comment: Please check logs using correlation ID. You can find there some proper error.

Comment: Don't you have to include the ".wsp" in the `File name` field?

Comment: I'll trying with ".wsp" in file name but problem is the same..

Comment: Did you see this related question? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60719/error-copying-temporary-solution-file-to-solutions-gallery

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the "include content" box and see if that works first - just to prove that making templates does work.

If it does work then increase the maximum size of the templates you are able to create by running the following:

```
param([string]$TemplateDocSize = 50000000)

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration")


write-host "Getting Current Template Document Size"
$contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
write-host "Current Size:" $contentService.MaxTemplateDocumentSize
write-host "Resetting to Size:" 
$contentService.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = $TemplateDocSize
$contentService.Update()
write-host "New Size: " $contentService.MaxTemplateDocumentSize
```

Copied from:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Increase-the-template-97276459

Comment: Does Not working with unchecked "include content"...

Comment: I assume you are a site collection administrator otherwise you wouldn't have access to the options, but it may be a permissions issue if you are not.  Also can you try it on a brand new empty site collection with no customisations active?  I wonder if there is something enabled or configured in the site that is preventing it from saving.  'Workflow' is mentioned for instance in the error message so that may be an indication of a potential issue.

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue. Many other are the same so it's safe to assume it's nothing related to anything you've done. I got word back on a ticket i submitted to MS saying that its an issue "affecting UK customers" but it seems that the Save as Template feature for publishing sites is now completely disabled